# Changing xticklabels or yticklabels independently between different plots in a Seaborn FacetGrid

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn, facet-grid

I am grouping pairs of bar plots using FacetGrid and would like to change the ticklabels for the bars individually. The ticklabels between the different facets seemed to be linked though, so that changing one will change them all.

For example, we may have stores in a city where the driving distance is not the same in one direction than it is in the other, due to one way streets. In such a situation we may have distances like this:

|  | kmart | walmart | target |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| kmart | 0 | 10.2 | 6.0 |
| walmart | 8.3 | 0 | 9.1 |
| target | 9.0 | 7.2 | 0 |

I can make a bar chart that has a bar for each journey (e.g. kmart -> walmart), that groups the distances by (source, destination) so that kmart -> walmart is next to walmart -> kmart:

[image: Bar chart describing distances]

```py
from pandas import DataFrame                
import seaborn as sns; sns.set_theme()


data = [[('kmart', 'walmart'), 'store1', 10.2],                
        [('kmart', 'walmart'), 'store2', 8.3],                                  
        [('kmart', 'target'), 'store1', 6.0],                                   
        [('kmart', 'target'), 'store2', 9.0],                                   
        [('walmart', 'target'), 'store1', 9.1],                                 
        [('walmart', 'target'), 'store2', 7.2]]                                 
                                                                                
df = DataFrame(data, columns=['pair', 'store', 'distance'])                     
                                                                                
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row='pair', height=1, aspect=7, ylim=(0.4, 1.0))          
g.map(sns.barplot, 'distance', 'store', order=['store1', 'store2'])             

g.set_titles('')                                                                
g.fig.show()
```

Instead of seeing "store1" and "store2" on each line I would like to see the name of the journey (e.g. the top bar would be labeled "kmart -> walmart" instead of "store1", the second would be "walmart -> kmart" instead of "store2"). I tried to do this by iterating over the axes and setting the yticklabels manually:

```py
journeys = ['kmart -> walmart', 'walmart -> kmart',                             
            'kmart -> target', 'target -> kmart',                               
            'walmart -> target', 'target -> walmart']                           
i = 0                                                                           
for ax in g.axes.flat:                                               
  ax.set_yticklabels(journeys[i:i+2])                                           
  i += 2                              
                                                                   
g.fig.tight_layout()
g.fig.show()
```

The result is not what I expected, however, as it looks like the yticklabels between the different axes are linked (i.e. you change the label "store1" and all the "store1" labels change).

[image: The yticklabels are tied together]

Is there a way to change the yticklabels individually using the elements of the matplotlib figure?

Comment: Maybe `g = sns.FacetGrid(...., sharey=False)` works for you?

Comment: Interesting quirk. Can you try wtih `ax.set_yticklabels(journeys[i:i+2][:])`?

Comment: @JohanC: that does work.  Thanks!  Strange `sharey` is not described in the "Parameter" section of the documentation!?  Do you want to make an answer out of it?

Comment: Turns out it _is_ documented as `share{x,y}`.

Comment: The documentation uses an abbreviated form. By the way, you can use `for pair in g.axes_dict: g.axes_dict[pair].set_yticklabels([f'{pair[0]} --> {pair[1]}', f'{pair[1]} --> {pair[0]}'])` to set the labels without creating the additional list.

Comment: @JohanC: very nice!

Answer (score 0):

With help of [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70290498/changing-xticklabels-or-yticklabels-independently-between-different-plots-in-a-s#comment124254013_70290498) of @JohanC, I have the following code to produce what I wanted.  The key is to use the `sharey=False` parameter when instantiating a FacetGrid.

```py
from pandas import DataFrame
import seaborn as sns; sns.set_theme()


data = [[('kmart', 'walmart'), 'store1', 10.2],
        [('kmart', 'walmart'), 'store2', 8.3],
        [('kmart', 'target'), 'store1', 6.0], 
        [('kmart', 'target'), 'store2', 9.0],
        [('walmart', 'target'), 'store1', 9.1],
        [('walmart', 'target'), 'store2', 7.2]]
                                               
df = DataFrame(data, columns=['pair', 'journey', 'distance'])
                                                             
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row='pair', height=1, aspect=7, ylim=(0.4, 1.0), sharey=False) 
g.map(sns.barplot, 'distance', 'journey', order=['store1', 'store2']) 
                                                               
for pair in g.axes_dict:                                       
    g.axes_dict[pair].set_yticklabels([f'{pair[0]} --> {pair[1]}', f'{pair[1]} --> {pair[0]}'])
                                                               
g.set_titles('')                                               
g.fig.tight_layout()                                           
g.fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: You can also use a UTF-8 character for the right arrow.  E.g.  `f'{pair[0]} ⮕ {pair[1]}'`